# R xml parse uniprot features

Tags: r, xml

I would like to extract information from a specific XML node using R from: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P38949.xml. It concerns the following block:

```
    <feature type="initiator methionine" description="Removed" evidence="1">
<location>
  <position position="1"/>
</location>
    </feature>
    <feature type="chain" description="Major pollen allergen Car b 1 isoforms 1A and 1B" id="PRO_0000154185">
<location>
  <begin position="2"/>
  <end position="160"/>
</location>
    </feature>
    <feature type="sequence variant" description="In isoform 1B.">
<original>V</original>
<variation>A</variation>
<location>
  <position position="38"/>
</location>
    </feature>
    <feature type="sequence variant" description="In isoform 1B.">
<original>I</original>
<variation>S</variation>
<location>
  <position position="63"/>
</location>
    </feature>
    <feature type="sequence variant" description="In isoform 1B.">
<original>K</original>
<variation>E</variation>
<location>
  <position position="133"/>
</location>
    </feature>
```

I attempted to extract the feature type="sequence variant" node using the following code:

```
    TabName = "P38949"
    http = paste0("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/",TabName,".xml")
    data = xmlParse(http)
    nd = getNodeSet(data, "//ns:entry", namespaces=c(ns=getDefaultNamespace(data)[[1]]$uri))

    original = sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './/*[local-name()="original"]', xmlValue)
    variation = sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './/*[local-name()="variation"]', xmlValue)
    description =  sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './/*[local-name()="feature" and @type="sequence variant"]', xmlGetAttr, 'description')

    position =  sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './/*[local-name()="position"]', xmlGetAttr, 'position')

    table = rbind(table, data.frame(description,original,variation,position))
```

I am not able to extract the the position attribute correctly, since the script also extracts the position attribute of feature type="initiator methionine", which is not want I want. The output table should look like this:

```
       description original variation position
    In isoform 1B.        V         A       38  
    In isoform 1B.        I         S       63
    In isoform 1B.        K         E      133
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rvest` (a slightly more convenient `xml2` 'version') and `purrr`:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

read_xml('http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P38949.xml') %>% 
    xml_nodes(xpath = '//d1:feature[@type="sequence variant"]') %>% 
    map_df(~{

        description <- xml_attr(.x, 'description')

        original    <- xml_node(.x, xpath = 'd1:original') %>%
                             xml_text()

        variation   <- xml_node(.x, xpath = 'd1:variation') %>% 
                             xml_text()

        position    <- xml_node(.x, xpath = 'd1:location/d1:position') %>% 
                             xml_attr('position')

        data.frame(description, original, variation, position,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
#>      description original variation position
#> 1 In isoform 1B.        V         A       38
#> 2 In isoform 1B.        I         S       63
#> 3 In isoform 1B.        K         E      133
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the sequence variant nodes, `flatten` the `xmlToList` output, and bind that into a table.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

variants <- getNodeSet(data, "//ns:feature[@type='sequence variant']", "ns")
bind_rows(lapply(variants, function(x) flatten(xmlToList(x))))[, c(5,1:3)]
 # A tibble: 3 x 4
      description original variation position
            <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>
 1 In isoform 1B.        V         A       38
 2 In isoform 1B.        I         S       63
 3 In isoform 1B.        K         E      133
```